# How to load select option from database in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I Have been following zf2 guide for [blog](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html) I have created everything Controller, Factory, Form, Mapper, Model, Service, view etc

In my form I have a select element

```
$this->add(array(     
  'type' => 'select',       
  'name' => 'roleId',
  'attributes' =>  array(
    'id' => 'roleId',
    'options' => array(
        '1' => 'Admin',
        '2' => 'Manager',
    ),
  ),
  'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Role',
  ),
));
```

Now in this form I want to load the option for the role from the database.
I tried loading the option by creating a simple function, which can be accessed in the element as below, but Am not able to fetch the result. I have already created Controller, Factory, Form, Mapper, Model, Service and view, Where I can do CRUD operation on Role.

```
$this->add(array(     
  'type' => 'select',       
  'name' => 'roleId',
  'attributes' =>  array(
    'id' => 'roleId',
    'options' => $this->getAllRoles(),
  ),
  'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Role',
  ),
));

public function getAllRoles()
{
  $roles = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Service\RoleService');
  $allRoles = $this->getAllTheRoles();  
  return $allroles;
}
```

Can anybody guide me how can I load all the Roles in option as listed in the IndexAction following [Blog Post](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html) with ID and Name of the Role.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a reusable form element that is pre-populated with the roles. To do so you must register the service with the form element manager in `module.config.php`.

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            'RoleSelect' => 'MyModule\Form\Element\RoleSelectFactory',
        ],
    ],
];
```

There is not need to extend the standard select class as the changes are configuration only. This is best done in a factory class.

```
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\Select;

class RoleSelectFactory
{
    public function __invoke($formElementManager, $name, $rname)
    {
        $select = new Select('role_id');

        $select->setOptions(['label' => 'Role']);
        $select->setAttributes(['id' => 'role_id']);

        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $roleService = $serviceManager->get('Admin\Service\RoleService');

        $options = [];
        foreach($roleService->getAllTheRoles() as $role){
            $options[$role->getId()] => $role->getName();
        }

        $select->setValueOptions($options);

        return $select;
    }
}
```

Adding the element within a form can then be updated to use the name of the service we registered.

```
$this->add([     
    'name' => 'role_id'
    'type' => 'RoleSelect',       
]);
```

One important point to remember is that the *form* using this element must be created using the `$formElementManager->get('FormWithRoleSelect')`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP : I tried the way you told but still am getting the error as "Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for RoleSelect"

Comment: If you are then it is most likely you need to move the adding of the form elements [from `__construct` to the `init()` method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements) in your form.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found out the simple way to do this, Am really not sure if this is the correct way.

Added the Role service in the User Controller

Code in my userController.php

```
use Admin\Service\RoleServiceInterface;
class UserController extends AbstractActionController
{
  /**
  * @var \Admin\Service\UserServiceInterface
  */
  protected $userService;
  protected $roleService;
  protected $userForm;

  public function __construct(
    UserServiceInterface $userService,
    RoleServiceInterface $roleService,
    FormInterface $userForm
  )
  {
    $this->userService = $userService;
    $this->roleService = $roleService;
    $this->userForm    = $userForm;
  }

  public function addAction()
  {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $roles    = $this->roleService->findAllRoles();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
      if($role->getStatus() == 1) {
        $allRoles[$role->getId()] = $role->getName();
      }
    }
    $this->userForm->__construct(null, array('roleOptions'=>$allRoles));
  }
}
```

My UserControllerFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Factory;

use Admin\Controller\UserController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
  /**
  * Create service
  *
  * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
  {
    $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    $userService        = $realServiceLocator->get('Admin\Service\UserServiceInterface');
    $roleService        = $realServiceLocator->get('Admin\Service\RoleServiceInterface');
    $userInsertForm     = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('Admin\Form\UserForm');

    return new UserController(
    $userService,
    $roleService,
    $userInsertForm
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the UserForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Admin\Model\User;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Zend\Form\Element\Select;


class UserForm extends Form
{
  public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
  {
    $roleOptions = array();
    if($options) {
      $roleOptions = $options['roleOptions'];
    }
    parent::__construct($name, $options);

    $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false));
    $this->setObject(new User());
    $this->add(array(
      'type' => 'hidden',
      'name' => 'id'
    ));

   $this->add(array(     
     'type' => 'select',       
     'name' => 'roleId',
     'attributes' =>  array(
       'id' => 'roleId',
       'options' => $roleOptions
     ),
    'options' => array(
      'label' => 'Role',
    ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This way using service manager I was successfully able to load the data in my for Select option.

Comment: This isn't the ZF2 way, your controller should never need to construct the form. This does however show what I thought; the form elements should be added within the `init()` method not `__construct`, if you make this change my answer will work.

Comment: @AlexP: I followed the link, http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html. Let me know if you have any other link for me to follow.

Comment: I've added a link to my answer as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Call `getAllRoles()` inside the controller then You can pass your custom array as parameter for `form` when you create `form` object. In `form` __construct function you can retrieve that array and set like this

> 'options' => $roles,