# Doctrine Select - how to select specific users data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

So I have a one-to-many association between a user table and user creditors. When writing reports a user needs to select which of his or her creditors to connect to. The problem I am having is that I want to return only the logged in users creditors using DoctrineSelect and not every creditor in the database. I am not sure how to limit DoctrineSelect to the ID of the logged in user.

**This is what I have done so far:**

customer -> creditor

In my fieldset I have the following:

```
    $this->add(
        [
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'creditor',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                'target_class'   => 'Debtor\Entity\Creditor',

                'label_generator' => function($targetEntity) {
                        return $targetEntity->getTitle() . ' - ' . $targetEntity->getFirstName() . ' - ' . $targetEntity->getLastName();
                    },
                'label' => 'Creditor',
                'instructions' => 'Attach creditors to this report'

            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => 'required',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

This unfortunately attaches all creditors to the form as apposed to the ones belonging to the user.

So to resolve this I created the following class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;
use Debtor\Service\CreditorService;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement as BaseFormElement;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;

class FormElement extends BaseFormElement
{
    public function __construct(
        CreditorService $creditorService
    )
    {
        $this->creditorService = $creditorService;
    }

    /**
     * This function overrides the ZendFormElement method which allows us to set the format of our own elements if required
     * @param ElementInterface $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render( ElementInterface $element )
    {

        $attributes = $element->getAttributes();

        if ( isset( $attributes['customElement']) )
        {
            $customElement = $attributes['customElement'];

            switch( $customElement ) {

                case 'getCreditors':
                    $creditors = $this->creditorService->findUserCreditors();
                    $element->setValueOptions( $creditors );
                    break;
            }
        }

        return parent::render($element);
    }
}
```

In my fieldset I now have this:

```
$this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'select',
                'name' => 'creditor',
                'options' => [
                    'label' => 'Creditor',
                    'instructions' => 'Attach creditors to this report',
                ],
                'attributes' => [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => 'required',
                    'class' => 'form-control input-medium select2me',
                    'customElement' => 'getCreditors',  <-*****************
                ]
            ]
        );
```

Where my class looks for the customElement, if found it returns the customers creditors using the following code in my creditors service:

```
 /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function findUserCreditors()
    {
        $creditors = $this->findByUserAuth();
        $creditorArray = [];

        foreach ($creditors AS $creditorObject)
        {
            $creditorArray[$creditorObject->getId()] = $creditorObject->getName();
        }

        return $creditorArray;

    }
```

This works a treat with one small problem. When I edit a report, the form is not pre-selecting the previously selected creditors in the drop down...

**My question though is this:**

Is there a way to use DoctrineSelect and using my AuthenticationService, get the logged in users ID and return the specific data?

Comment: Why not [create a custom select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825701/how-to-load-select-option-from-database-in-zf2/34829272#answer-34829272). All you would need is a service factory registered with the form element manager. This factory could populate the options and fetch the authenticated user. Unless the select element is very simple, I personally feel there is never any need to use the Doctrine  `ObjectSelect` over a custom element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution.

Using Example 3 from [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) and the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246939/zf2-doctrine-2-objectselect-with-distinct-on-field).

I have done the following:

1. Created a repository
2. Injected my auth service into my form and included the authService as a param in the field.

My fieldset:

```
    $this->add(
        [
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'creditor',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Creditor: ',
                'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                'target_class' => 'Debtor\Entity\Report',
                'property' => 'Report',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => [
                    'name' => 'findUserCreditors',
                    'params' => [
                        'authService' => $this->authService
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => 'required',
                'class' => 'form-control input-medium select2me',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

And added a repository to my report entity by updating the annotations as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="report")
 */
class Report
{
```

And finally added the repository class:

```
<?php
namespace Debtor\Entity;

use Customer\Service\AuthenticationService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CreditorRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findUserCreditors(AuthenticationService $authService)
    {
        $userObject = $authService->getIdentity();

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.created', 'ASC');

        $qb->where('c.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user' , $userObject );

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

If you are struggling or getting an error, dump the repository data and make sure it is returning the correct objets.